# Choosing a Main Image in a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I have the following two models:

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = RichTextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    volunteers = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    sdgs = models.ManyToManyField(SDG)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'


class EventPhoto(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='events/photos')
```

A single **Event** object can contain multiple photos, maybe 1, maybe 10 or maybe 100.

I am using the following code inside of my *admin.py* file.

```py
class EventPhotosInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = EventPhotos

@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EventPhotosInline,]
```

The above code allows me to add EventPhoto objects while I am adding a new event in the admin dashboard.

My question is, how would I go about choosing on of the many photos to be the main photo of the event? I could of easily created an image field inside the **Event** model with the name **main_photo**, but in the future if I have to change the main photo I have to upload a new one, all I need is to just use one of the many uploaded images as my main photo.

How would I go about creating something similar to what I want?!

I also tried adding a boolean field to the **EventPhoto** model which adds a checkbox, but when I check one of the checkboxes and then try to choose another photo, both of them gets selected, I want only one, so to deselect the old one and select the new one.

I hope my idea is clear to you guys, and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I think there is way to override the widget of a field... please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides

Comment: @shourav it is not way I am exactly looking for I think. Could you please show me an example which control should I use instead, if I went through and changed the default one?